# Concurrent multiple external executables and DAQ in LabVIEW

Tags: labview, nidaqmx

I am using LabVIEW 2009 with USB 6008 for DAQ from accelerometers. Besides, DAQ from the accelerometers, I have couple of other external executables which triggers the two different process (data write). By using System Exec.vi, I can trigger these external executables. But the external executables data writing starts at different time, as an example, say exe1 takes 1 second long to start writing data to a text file, where as exe2 takes 20 seconds long to initialize and to start writing data.

Therefore, is there any way even I trigger multiple external exe files, and I can start data write from all of them at the same instance along with DAQ from accelerometers.

Thank you and much appreciated for your help

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the 6008 by heart, but you could set a start-trigger (hardware) for the data generation. So when you start generating one task, the other task starts as well. But you have to make sure that both tasks are ready or your timeout is long enough.

Comment: Alright Ton, thanks for your suggestion, I will try something similar to this.

Comment: The USB-6008 manual at http://www.ni.com/pdf/manuals/371303m.pdf says you can use the PFI 0 input to trigger analogue acquisition.